# Everything "below" the bone stays in place

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I am trying to rig a human armature and on some parts (elbows, hands, and wrists mainly) the rest of the mesh that is "below" the bone stays in the same spot. Is there any way to fix this or do I have to restart?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFLfO.jpg (This shows what happens)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bone parenting problem: Some of the bones are not parented to the bones they are supposed to be patented to, or their relationship is set up incorrectly so that the children bones do not move with the parents. There also appear to be some vertex weight problems, but since (per the mentioned problem) the “below” mesh *and the related bones* aren’t moving, I doubt that weights is the majority of the issue.

Fixing the issue will likely happen in Edit mode on the armature, but without specific details on the model, little can be done on my side.

PS: Use the built-in image attaching system for stackexchange questions.